# Optimal Database connection string for high traffic connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I just want to know, What parameters or attributes should be taken in connection string so as to handle high traffic enterprise applications?
Like in general we use server, initial catalog, userid, passwd. Some times we add timeout , and in some scenario pool etc. But i don't know what attributes should i take in as my common practice apart from above.

Comment: not exactly your question but this page shows all possible and valid connectionstrings for all different databases out there: http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: i know.. this site and always use this as referenec, but i want to know from SO guru's is there any tweak or trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any event make sure you reuse the same connection string throughout the app so as to enable connection pooling.

Comment: Connection pooling is a must for high-throughput applications. Generally though I wouldn't bother with caching - it usually just means you haven't put enough effort into optimising your queries.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely dont want to persist the connection.  probably want to move towards a client dataset loading so the users carry the load of data but then again you may want to review your Database farm configuration with virtualizing.

if you are talking about well over 1 million hits, creating a DB farm with a load balancer would be your best configuration.  Another path is to seperate your DB request from the application and through a Web Service type interface to manage the connections.

if less than 1 Million hits, then its best to manage the resources through the application but better have some good dba's to manage the pipes and throttle when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If a lot of the data is read-only and repeatable, caching can be your best friend.